# Route on search submit

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to route a different component based on the url generated from a search bar component

url generated after submit:

```
http://localhost:3000/?search=tetris#/
```

I have the code below for my return but I've been struggling to make it work:

```
return (
    <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={props => 
            <div>
                <Navi />
                <SearchBox />
                <CardGroup games={postsPerPage} posts={currentPosts}  loading={loading}/>
                <Pagination postsPerPage={postsPerPage} totalPosts={posts.length} paginate={paginate} />
             </div> 
                }/>
        <Route path="/games/:games" exact  component={Content} />
        <Route path={`/?search=${query}#/`} component={CardGroupSearch} />
    </Switch>
    </Router>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useQuery hook for getting the query string parameters

Read more here https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters